# Launching app via URI fails

Tags: c#, batch-file, windows-runtime, uri, launch

I associated a `Uri` with my App to launch it via a simple batch program containing just this line:

```
start myappname:
```

Usually, when I start my App the splash screen is shown for a second and the app continues accordingly after that.
But when I launch the app via the batch program, the app will never go past the splash screen. It gets stuck there.
However if the app has been opened before this way of activating it works.

Need some guidance here on what could the problem be or what could be causing this issue.

Thanks.

Edit: 
here is the declaration of the asscociation of the uri in the package manifest.

```
<Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.protocol">
      <Protocol Name="myappname" m2:DesiredView="default">
        <Logo>Assets\MiniLogo.png</Logo>
        <DisplayName>myApp</DisplayName>
      </Protocol>
    </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

Comment: double every percent sign

Comment: I don't have any. I just use the line shown above.

Comment: then try like `start "" myappname:`  - first argument is always taken for title in start command.

Comment: What's the purpose of the colon?

Comment: @Ian - this points to a registered network/application protocol (like http:...)

Comment: @npocmaka Ok.. new one on me! Thanks.

Comment: @npocmaka this seems to have influence. When defining a startpage in the manifest, this leads to a blank page.